# Do I need an external package for decoding Base 64 in Android?

Tags: android, database, base64

I am currently working on an Android project in which I need to extract an image from a database. The image is saved in Base 64 code, and the datatype in the table is BLOB.

I have read about decoding Base 64, and now I am uncertain if I need an external package (for example, org.apache.commons.codec.binary) or is it now included since api 8 (from link: [How to use Base64 (included in android since api 8 (2.2)) in a android project api 3 (android 1.5)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836760/how-to-use-base64-included-in-android-since-api-8-2-2-in-a-android-project-ap))?

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since API level 8 (Android 2.2), there is the following class:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html

or

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64InputStream.html

If you're targetting a lower SDK version, then I'd recommend using the class found there: http://androidcodemonkey.blogspot.com/2010/03/how-to-base64-encode-decode-android.html

Answer (score 0):

If you're app is targeting only OS2.2 and later, then you can use the Base64 class (android.util.Base64).

Otherwise, as the link you included suggests, you'll have to include your own Base64 class to handle earlier OS versions.