# Serialize image to string

Tags: java, android, serialization

Good friends.

A couple of months I am looking for a way to serialize an image I have stored in a imageView.

This image was taken by the camera and start the ImageView, but the question esque need serialize and pass it to a text string.

I have searched high and low on google and forums, but none have found an answer.

Anyone know some method of how I can do?.

Comment: Have you tried going just doing a binary convert to unicode or plain chars? I mean, just going over the binary data of the colors pixel by pixel and saving that as char values? Also, what about streams? any stream can end up being a bytestream which can then be converted to a text stream or something.

Comment: Are you just looking to serialize an Image object to a UTF encoded string?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to move binary data around safely as text, you could Base64 encode the binary data. If you are using an Android API that doesn't include the Base64 utils, see: [How to use Base64 (included in android since api 8 (2.2)) in a android project api 3 (android 1.5)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836760/how-to-use-base64-included-in-android-since-api-8-2-2-in-a-android-project-a)

Once your binary data is Base64 encoded it can be safely passed through systems that are only expecting 'plain' ascii text.

Bear in mind that your bitmap data will be uncompressed and will therefore generate a large amount of text when Base64 encoded (Base64 encoding results in the bytes required to represent the data increasing by 1/3). To mitigate this you should compress the `Bitmap` image data before Base64 encoding it, using something like:

```
try
{
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(8192);
    bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, COMPRESSION_AMOUNT, baos);     
    byte[] compressedBytes = baos.toByteArray();
}
```

Where you want to set the COMPRESSION_AMOUNT to a value between 50-80 depending on the trade off between size and quality you are wanting.

Any clients recieving your data will first need to Base64 unencode, and then parse the resulting bytes as JPEG data to recreate the image.

Comment: I have a very similar method to compress and move the image to base64, but is a very large string, I think I would need something smaller, no matter what the image is rather small or pixelated, what I need is to serialize the image to send to the server using 3G technology.
Since I can compress even more so that the string is much smaller?

Comment: You can either up the compression (lower the `COMPRESSION_AMOUNT` value), or resize the image. You probably want to resize the image anyway, as some camera phones are starting to produce pretty hi-res images.